# how to use composite-id class element?

Tags: java, hibernate

when should you use the class element of the composite-id ?

for example, consider this snippet :

```
<composite-id name="id" ***class="OrderLineId"***>
    <key-property name="lineId"/>
    <key-property name="orderId"/>
    <key-property name="customerId"/>
</composite-id>

<property name="name"/>

<many-to-one name="order" class="Order"
        insert="false" update="false">
    <column name="orderId"/>
    <column name="customerId"/>
 </many-to-one>
  ....
```

for example, what is the purpose of OrderLineId above ?
how does it relate to other parts ?

Comment: Your question. 

I don't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "you shouldn't" :-)

It's generally a good idea to use a surrogate key in the first place; furthermore you'd make your mappings a lot simpler by using a single id instead of composite one. That said, there are situations (like mapping legacy schemas) when you need to use a composite key.

The above example shows how to map composite key as component. This is a better approach than using entity itself as its own key, which is what would happen if you were to map it without the `class` attribute on `<composite-id>`. The main differences are:

1. When mapping composite key as component, you'll write a new class (`OrderLineId`) that would contain mapped individual key parts (`lineId`, `orderId`, `customerId`) as properties. When mapping composite key on entity itself your entity class (`OrderLine`) would have to contain those properties.
2. In order to load `OrderLine` using "key as component" mapping, you'll create a new instance of `OrderLineId` and pass it to `session.get()` as key. Using "key on entity" mapping you will have to create an instance of `OrderLine` to load `OrderLine`, which is confusing at best and presents data integrity concerns at worst.